# code crashes when adding view

Tags: iphone, resources, viewcontroller

I copied all my iphone viewcontroller files into an a new iPad project. (I changed the sizes of each nib files etc.)
Almost all `viewControllers` are working except for one `viewcontroller` say `xview`.

At the line `[self.view add:xview.view]` the code crashes with the following log

```
2011-06-22 14:08:56.435 RelaxInAMinutePad[5073:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
2011-06-22 14:08:56.437 RelaxInAMinutePad[5073:207] Stack: (
    47421520,
    48579372,
    47159051,
    47158890,
    1569479,
    1563144,
    19971,
    20321,
    19638,
    23235,
    4095877,
    30247,
    5636593,
    3472622,
    3970110,
    3979456,
    3970037,
    3472622,
    3970110,
    3979456,
    3974253,
    3599848,
    3491395,
    3523032,
    56414588,
    46700700,
    46696616,
    56408221,
    56408418,
    3515250,
    8984,
    8838
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

I am not using any URL or anything from my code.
I am not getting why this is caused. I am sure this is not about coding but some thing to do with resources or IB.

what may be the mistake and how to rectify?

Comment: In the `.nib`, check the Reference Outlets (`Alt-2`) of `view` (and probably other UI objects).

Comment: In the .nib check for class name tab and outlets variable's connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the console:

```
  reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

Somewhere you are trying to instantiate an `NSURL` object, but the string you pass into it is `nil`.

Comment: i checked through the code once again there was a url being made for managedobjectmodel in the appdelegate like   NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myApp" ofType:@"momd"];
  NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];   this was being called at the time when adding the view and that url was being nil....

Answer (score 0):

check your line

```
 [self.view add xview.view]
```

it should be

```
 [self.view addSubview xview.view]
```

Comment: sorry that was a mistake while typing fast into this forum...actually i have used addSubview itself

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you not add Nib-file in new project, or any other resource files...